# BigQuery grouping by array and keeping array structure

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

Is there a neat way of grouping by arrays and aggregating across other columns in BigQuery, while keeping the array structure?

I have this table

[image]

and I want the below result

[image]

I realise I can GROUP BY `id` and `array_to_string(product,',')` and then SUM over `val`, but I would like to keep the array structure in the `product` column.

I've tried

```
select id, product, sum(val) as val
from my_table
group by id, product
```

but it seems that arrays cannot be used in a GROUP BY.

This doesn't seem to work either

```
select id, array(select val from unnest(split(array_to_string(product,','))) val) as product, sum(val) as val
from my_table
group by id, array_to_string(product,',')
```

the `array_to_string(product,',')` in the select statement is not recognised to be grouped/aggregated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider below approach.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT 2 id, [3] product, 5 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, [1, 2], 35 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, [1, 2], 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, [1], 40
)
SELECT ANY_VALUE(STRUCT(id, product)).*, SUM(val) AS val
  FROM sample_data
 GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', (id, product));
```

**Query results**

[image]